# Mysqli Problem: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Now this sounds and seems straightforward but am stuck really.

I try running this query

```
$sql="insert into employers (id, username, password, email, contact_person, company_name, location_country, location_state,     location_address, website, profile, logo, subdomain, activation_key, ipaddress) values ('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$params="$reg_username, $reg_password, $reg_email, $reg_contact_person, $reg_companyname, $reg_country, $reg_state, $reg_address, $reg_website, $reg_profile, $reg_logo, $reg_subdomain, $reg_activation_key, $reg_ip";

$resultobj=otherquery ($sql, "sssssssssbssss", $params);

function otherquery ($sql, $types, $params)
    {
       $connection = getConnect ();  
       $result = $connection->prepare("$sql");
       $result->bind_param($types, $params);
       $status = $result->execute();
       $result->store_result();
       $return=array('obj'=>$result, 'status' => $status, 'data'=>array());
       return $return; 
    }
```

and i keep getting this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /home/xyz/public_html/xyzabc.com/functions.php on line 69
```

What am i not counting correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$params` to store all your parameters: `bind_param()` sees only two parameters when called with `$params`, hence the error. You would have to pass them directly:

```
$result->bind_param($types, $reg_username, $reg_password, $reg_email, $reg_contact_person, ...);
```

Comment: this is an external that must be called externally. how do i handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I think i have fixed the problem:

I passed the parameters as an array to the function and used call_user_func_array.

```
$newparams = array_merge( (array) $types, $params);
call_user_func_array(array($result, 'bind_param'), $newparams);
```